# Is asking a question using photograph a good practice?

Tags: discussion, images

I have seen many times when a new user who has to post some big question(*which uses complicated symbols*) uses photographs and it is logical because they usually are not aware of MathJax.

But after sometime i see that there question is edited and photograph is removed.So my question is:

> if we upload question or answer rather than typing (*which is much time consuming and even tough*(*in my opinion*), it this a good practice or not?

will answering a question using photograph change the quality of post(*assume my handwritting is readible*)